# Android Java JSON parsing issue - missing attributes

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception

I am just parsing one JSON file in Android and my JSON is not consistent, meaning that some attributes and values are missing so I get null pointer exception. I have understood that we should check before extracting value of each attribute if he actually exists:

```
JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
if(!object.isNull("name"))
   String name = object.getString("name");
```

Since I have 12 parameters to extract the code does not looks nice.

Is there any more elegant solution?

Comment: use retrofit library for this

Comment: use `object.optString("name")`, you dont have need for check  isNull.

Comment: KuLdip PaTel .optString("name", ""); was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!